# Generic Swift class parametrized with a protocol fails at runtime. Why?

Tags: swift, generics

Given are two classes `A` and `PC` and the protocol `P`:

```
@objc public protocol P {} // fun fact on the side: without @objc, swiftc crashes

public class PC : P {}

public class A<T:P> {

    public init() { }

    public func test() -> Void {
        let pc = PC()
        let t = pc as T // this cast leads to the error mentioned below
    }
}
```

These compile fine.
Now I want to call `test()` like this:

```
let a = A<P>() // parametrized with the *protocol* P
a.test()
```

This also compiles nicely.

However, when I run it, and try to cast to `T` (via `pc as T`), the debugger lands in:

```
swift_dynamicCastUnknownClassUnconditional:
[...]
0x105fedf76:  leaq   0x3680f(%rip), %rax       ; "bad metadata kind!"
```

Why is that so?

I am assuming that because `T` is constrained by `P` and `PC` adopts `P`, every `PC` must also be a `T`.

Additional info—this:

```
let a = A<PC>() // parametrized with the *class*, not the protocol
a.test()
```

works like charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not surprised this code is problematic even if it seems like it ought to work at runtime, and you should probably refactor it to approach the problem differently.  It's possible that this is worthy of a radar, but I think that's debatable.  What it boils down to is that I don't believe this line:

```
let t = pc as T
```

is a valid thing to do.  That `as` is saying "no matter what `pc` is, I want  to make it of type `T`."  But there are no guarantees that this is OK.  What about the following:

```
extension String: P { }
let x = A<String>()
```

The above is perfectly acceptable declaration – `String` conforms to `P` and so you can create an `A` where `T` is `String`.  But you cannot write `let pc = PC(); let t = pc as String` – `PC` and `String` are totally unrelated types.  If you tried to do this in non-generic code, you'd get a compiler error.  With the generic version, you're kind of in a netherworld – the generic function is supposed to be like saying "at compile time, assuming `T` were replaced with an actual type, write me a function that's just like that".  It's really not clear how `as T` should be interpreted in those circumstances – it might fail at compile-time, it might not.

Now you might argue "it's OK, I'll always make sure any when I call create my class I only do it with types that will work.  It'll never crash because I'll never call it with something that will crash".  And that's the case in your example.

But that's not the way Swift generics operate – Swift does its best to make sure possible what occurs inside a generic is always valid for any type that matches the generic criteria.  Just because, in the way you're calling it here, it happens to work, and you've convinced Swift to let it compile does not make the code valid and as a result, the behaviour you're observing seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks for producing an example that makes it obvious where my thinking went astray..